# Wrap yaml data in single quotes

Tags: regex, awk, sed, yaml

I would like to wrap all of my `YAML` data (in a large file) with single quotes.  I tried `sed`, but it did not work:

```
sed "s/\(.*: \)\(.*\)/\1'\2'/" <data.yml >datanew.yml
```

This took lines like this:

```
location_id: 25
street: 
text: This is text: it contains colons
```

And produced lines like:

```
' location_id: '25
' street: '
' text: This is text: 'it contains colons
```

... but I would like them to look like:

```
location_id: '25'
street: ''
text: 'This is text: it contains colons'
```

Is this possible in `sed` (or `awk` or `perl` or ...)?  From my research, it seems like `sed` may have trouble picking up the first colon since it matches greedy.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

**Additional Information**

Note `YAML` has optional leading whitespace, a token followed by a colon and everything else on the line (which could include one or more additional colons) all of which needs to be wrapped in quotes.

You can test with the above three lines.

**More**

Thank you all for your suggestions.  I am assuming most of them actually work, but not for me.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwRV5.jpg) is a snapshot from my terminal using one of the suggested patterns.  Unfortunately they all fail for me in roughly the same way.

Even more frustrating, when I open the file in `vim` and run search and replace with that same pattern, it works perfectly.  I tried to use that technique for my whole file, but `vim` wasn't pleased with the 4M lines.

Is my `sed` somehow broken??

Comment: Could you post a sample yml file that you're working with?

Comment: Sorry about that @Alejandro.  I've updated the original post with the sample input lines.

Comment: Hey @steve klein, I changed my response a tad, I had something else in mind when I wrote it the first time. Could you see if the updated one fits your requirements?

Comment: HI @steveklein I also updated my answer, which is a sed one liner. Can you see if it's suitable for your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex:

```
^\s*([^:]+)(:\s)(.*?)\s*$
```

Does what you want. [Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX5oG6/1)

It is easiest to express in Perl.

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
 location_id: 25
 street: 
 text: This is text: it contains colons
```

In Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne "print if s/^\s*([^:]+)(:\s)(.*?)\s*$/\1\2'\3'/"
location_id: '25'
street: ''
text: 'This is text: it contains colons'
```

Comment: Works great for one line @dawg.  Unfortunately I do not know `Perl`.  How would I go about iterating through each line in a source file and generating an output file?

Comment: Perl is like sed in this case: with the command line args `-lne` there is an implicit loop over the lines input into it. So `perl -lne 'print if s/regex/\1/' file` will read all the lines in file, perform the regex substitution, print that line if successful. Try it on your file.

Comment: So close I can taste it @dawg!  I should have mentioned that the file contains some lines without colons which I want to be left (copied) as is.  Can you suggest a tweak to accommodate?

Comment: Also, on closer examination, it looks like this is not maintaining the spacing at the start of each line.  This is important because `YAML` is format sensitive.  OK I've fixed that part with `perl -lne "print if s/^(\s*)([^:]+)(:\s)(.*?)\s*$/\1\2\3'\4'/"`.

Comment: Thanks @Dawg.  After several other attempts, sanity breaks, etc., I came back to this.  Obviously, I can `cat` my file to your sweet little `Perl` and then it is just a matter of putting back the rest of the `YAML`.  A little bit of `sed` and I am well on my way.

Comment: Great. Know that you do not *need* to `cat` the file. You can do `perl -lne 'perl_one_line_program' your_file > out_put_file` too.

Answer (score 0):

Little change in your sed

```
sed "s/\([^:]*: \)\(.*\)/\1'\2'/" <data.yml >datanew.yml
```

Comment: I've just checked with your provided input, it's working here. Using gnu sed 4.2.2

Comment: Also, to .* not be greedy, .*? can be used

Comment: I'm showing the same version:  sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.  I just tried to run with your pattern again and it still does not work.  It almost seems like it is trying to wrap \1 with quotes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` you can use:

```
cat file
Some other data
location_id: 25
street:
```

```
awk -v f="'" -F": *" 'NF==2 {$NF=f $NF f}1' file
Some other data
location_id '25'
street ''
```

It test if line has `:`, and if then it wraps `'` around last filed, empty or not.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Note `YAML` has optional leading whitespace, a token followed by a colon and everything else on the line (which could include one or more additional colons) all of which needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for the test cases you provided, as well as some cases I came up with:

```
sed "s/\([^:]*:\s*\)\(.*\)/\1'\2'/g"
```

The way it works is by doing a non-greedy match for text up until a colon, then followed by a colon and optional whitespace with `[^:]*:\s*` . All of that is put into a capture group. The reason I need the "then followed by a colon" is because some lines such as "%YAML 1.1" which appear in the file would match the regex, even though they should not be included. By adding the additional constraint that there be a colon, such lines are excluded from replacement.

The next part is relatively easy, just match any text following the previous capture group. This an be achieved with `.*` (which also included colons, as you mentioned above in your question).

The sed `s` command is used to replace the regex matched with the first capture group,`\1`, which is all the text up until the first colon and optional whitespace, followed by the 2nd capture group `\2` which is all the text after the colon and whitespace, in single quotes.

Here's a demo of it:

[regex test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwAhQ.png)